# Form submission with two buttons "save" and "save & submit"?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have one form with around 50 fields and two submit buttons, "SAVE" and "SAVE & SUBMIT". If the user clicks "SAVE", then insert the value up to which user have filled in the form. When user clicks "SAVE & SUBMIT" button, it should update or insert all the fields which user have filled in the form. Please help me out if any one have any solution. I am newbie.

```
<form id="myform">
<input type="text" name="field1" />
<br/>
<input type="text" name="field2" />
<br/>
<input type="text" name="field3" />
<br/>
<input type="text" name="field4" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" id="button1" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" id="button2" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

From the above form if user have entered values in field1 and field2 and then click on save the data should insert in the mysql and if user have fill all the fields then user can click on save and submit then data should update or insert in the mysql.

Comment: And... what do you want?... what have you tried?, please, be more concise

Comment: @Dani I have edited the question please check

Comment: @SameerSashittal I still don't understand what you are asking? Please try to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set value for the fields which the user have entered before. Otherwise check if there is no insertion in mysql then insert a new row while clicking save button or else update mysql on clicking save and submit button.

```
 <input type="text" name="field1"  value={value} />
```

Kindly refer these for better understanding.

https://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/1969-basic-php-system-vieweditdeleteadd-records/

http://falkencreative.com/forum/records/view.php